# Filter out characters in one UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Ok, I am trying to edit this one text field that is txtCountry to not accept certain letters, but I can't, because the txt country is not setup right. Can someone please fix this up for me. I probably making some kind of little detail mistake.

```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
if ([textField isEqual: txtCountry]) {

NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:LEAGELNUM] invertedSet];
NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs]     componentsJoinedByString:@""];
BOOL basicTest = [string isEqualToString:filtered];
return basicTest;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to insert the name of the text field into the method. Instead do this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField isEqual: txtCountry]) {
        //return YES or NO here depending on your criteria
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i did it but I got a public void error, can you help me with this part.I updated my question.

Comment: @moo Don't say “I got a public void error”.  Copy and paste the exact error text, *and* the code that generates the error.